# rsyncing to a new destination, but files are already there. Can I rsync know not to resend the all the files?

Tags: backup, rsync

Our current setup consists of about 100 remote sites that gather data and then once a week transfer that data to a local server using rsync over a cellular connection.  The data is stored at the remote sites for 12 months before it is deleted.  All remote sites have been operating for more than a year.  (They have a year's worth of data but only send down a weeks worth of data at a time.)
  Recently our server needed to be replaced.  All of the data for the sites has been backed up and that data has been put onto the new server.
  I did a test using one of the remote sites and manually forced a push of data using rsync to the new server.  It worked, but instead of pushing just the new data, it pushed all of the data for the past year, even though the data already existed on the new server it was pushing to.  Rsync appeared to not recognize that most of the files already existed on the new server.  (After the test sync, there were not duplicate files on the server, so rsync either overwrote the files are re-wrote them with the same data as before.)

Here is my question: How can I get rsync to recognize that the files it is trying to push already exist on the new server and not push down files that are already on the server?

This may seem like a trivial question, because after rsync runs one time on each remote site, everything will have flushed out.  However, because my connections are cellular and I pay for the data I use.  Sending a years worth of data, while my cellular plans are based on sending a months worth of data will result is severe overages in data usage costing us a lot of money.  I have until Sunday morning at 2 AM to figure something out, otherwise all of the remote sites will start to download all the data they have stored for the past year.
  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We found that using rsync to copy the data from the old server to the new server fixed the issue.  Apparently rsync whatever metadata was being looked at by the rsync program.  Our first two attempts used scp and a USB stick to copy files.  These methods did not work.